# An easier and more efficient way to combine lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I currently have a two lists. The first list contains independent variables $x$, and the second list contains dependent variables in the form of $\{\{f[1][x]\},\{f[2][x]\},...,\{f[n][x]\}\}$.

I want to combine them in the form 
$$\{\{\{x1,f[1][x1]\},\{x2,f[1][x2]\},...,\{xn,f[1][xn]\}\},\{\{x1,f[2][x1]\},\{x2,f[2][x2]\},...,\{xn,f[2][xn]\}\},...,\{\{x1,f[n][x1]\},\{x2,f[n][x2]\},...,\{xn,f[n][xn]\}\}\}$$
 ...an easy format for `ListPlot`.

For some example data:

```
a = Range[10];
b = a^2;
c = (a + 1/2)^2;
fa = {b,c};
```

Now one can easily do this with `Table`:

```
Table[{a[[j]], fa[[i, j]]}, {i, Length[fa]}, {j, Length[c]}]
```

but knowing *Mathematica's* many functions I thought there might be an easier way. I tried this as well:

```
Transpose@MapThread[Tuples@{{#1}, #2} &, {a, Transpose@fa}]
```

but with the multiple `Transpose` calls, I figured there would be a slight performance hit. And there was (2.854 vs 3.261 seconds for vectors with 1MM elements on my machine).

Is there an easier and more efficient way to combine these lists?

Comment: So in your notation, `f[1][x1]` really means `f[[1,1]]` and not `SubValues`?

Comment: @rm-rf, Nah, it just means f[1] is a data vector that corresponds to the x-values. f[2] is another data vector not related to f[1]. Etc. Feel free to suggest another notation.

Comment: Also `MapThread[List, {a, #}] & /@ fa` will do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Thread[{a, #}] & /@ fa
```

or

```
Inner[List, a, #, List] & /@ fa
```

Comment: Yep. I love how I come up with `Transpose@MapThread[Tuples@{{#1}, #2} &, {a, Transpose@fa}]` but not `Thread[{a,#}]&/@fa`. Sigh. In any regards, the `Thread` method is 7.5x faster and the `Inner` method is 12x faster than the `MapThread` I suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @kale could you say how fast is `Array` in your setup?

Comment: @au700, You'll have to elaborate. Not sure I see a way to use `Array` to solve the problem...